# SWIFT: "Compressed" / small string type? 1 Byte per char?

Tags: string, swift, compression, character

I have to handle large textfiles. I known (and make sure) that they only use  codes < 255. So one byte (like in the old days) is enough. String and Character types are open to all languages. So I assume they will need much more than only one byte per letter. Is there a setting to use the small (risky) version of characters and strings in SWIFT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use UTF-8 in the files, for the characters in the ASCII range only one byte is used per character. The number of bytes increases only as needed to support other languages and characters such as emoji and flags.

Comment: Okay, so I don't need anything to improve, because it is already at its best!